# Is it possible to set partial view model values with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor

Data in the partial view depends on the user selection and I need to set the values of the model based on that.

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
   @{ int i = 0; }
   @foreach (var task in Model.Tasks.Where(x => x.IsCompleted == false))
   {
   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="openCurrentTaskModal(@task)">
      @task.Title
      <form method="post" id="formCompleteTask[@i]" asp-action="Complete" asp-controller="Task">
         <input type="hidden" name="taskId" value="@task.Id" />
         <input type="hidden" name="projectGuid" value="@Model.Guid" />
      </form>
      <a onclick="document.getElementById('formCompleteTask[@i]').submit();">
      <img src="~/img/circle.svg" alt="Complete" />
      </a>
   </li>
   i++;
   }
</ul>

<partial name="~/Views/Task/_CurrentTaskModalPartial.cshtml" model="new Taskly.Web.ViewModels.TaskViewModel()"/>
```

I want to populate the created view model with this function:

```
<script>
   function openCurrentTaskModal() {
       //set task parameter to view model
       $('#currentTaskModal').modal('show');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far, pls?

Comment: I don't know if what i want is even correct or possible. I read about knockout js but didn't manage to find anything useful...

Comment: Did you mean that you wanna change the display content when changing the selected options? And those content are in partial view?